# Android Value of Calendar getTimeInMillis() gets changed when passed to another Service

Tags: android, android-intent, parameters, android-calendar

I am facing a weird problem - time in milliseconds gets changed when passed from 1 service to another.

From an AsyncTask object in Service, this is my code that I use to set an alarm :

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.i("*** SetAlarmsTask", "In onPostExecute...");

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hrsPrior = 1;
        int interval = 15;
        boolean repeating = true;
        int[] dates;
        int[] times;
        long endTime;
        long intervalDuration = (1000 * 60 * interval);

        // handle your data
        for (Appointment apt: todaysAptsList) {
            Log.i("*** SetAlarmsTask", "APT DAte - " + apt.getAppointDate() + " Time = " + apt.getAppointTime());

           // DailySetNotifyService.SetAlarm(DailySetNotifyService.this, apt);

            cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            // Parse Date of Appointment
            dates = MainActivity.parseStringToDate(apt.getAppointDate());  
            // Set Calendar Date
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dates[0]);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, dates[1]-1);
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, dates[2]);

            // // Parse Time of Appointment
            times = MainActivity.parseStringToTime(apt.getAppointTime());  
            // Set Calendar Time
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, times[0]);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, times[1]);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();    // Apt Time
            Log.i("*** SetAlarmsTask", " END Time - " + String.valueOf(endTime) + " Apt Time - " + apt.getAppointTime() );   // END Time - 1413555000396 Apt Time - 10:10

            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) DailySetNotifyService.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            // Pass the endTime to Intent
            PendingIntent pIntent = getPendingIntent(endTime, (int)apt.getAptId(), apt); 
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);

            if (repeating) {
                int fromHr = times[0] - hrsPrior;
                int fromMin = times[1];
                Log.i("*** SetAlarmsTask", "Repeating set for Time " + String.valueOf(fromHr) + ":" +
                        String.valueOf(fromMin) + " wITH iNTERVAL : " + interval);  // Repeating set for Time 9:10 wITH iNTERVAL : 15

                // Pass the endTime to Intent
                pIntent = getPendingIntent(endTime, (int) apt.getAptId(), apt);

                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, fromHr);
                am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), intervalDuration, pIntent);
            }
        }

        stopSelf();
        Log.i("*** SetAlarmsTask", "In onPostExecute...FINISHED");
    }

    private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(long endTime, int reqCode, Appointment apt) {
        Intent i = new Intent(DailySetNotifyService.this, NotifyAlarmReceiver.class);
        i.putExtra("Appointment", apt);
        Log.i("*** SetAlarmsTask", " END Time - " + String.valueOf(endTime) );  //  END Time - 1413555000905  i.e 10:10 CORRECT

        // Send the endTime & requestCode to identify the time in Receiver and cancel the alarm
        // if it exceed the appointmentTime
        i.putExtra("endTime", endTime);
        i.putExtra("reqCode", reqCode);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(DailySetNotifyService.this, reqCode, i, 0);

        return pIntent;
    }
```

The receiver `NotifyAlarmReceiver`, where I receive the event code is :

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       long now = cal.getTimeInMillis(); //System.currentTimeMillis();
       Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
       Appointment apt = (Appointment)b.get("Appointment");
       long end = b.getLong("endTime");
       int reqCode = b.getInt("reqCode");

       Log.i("***NotifyAlarmReceiver", "Now - " + String.valueOf(now) + " END - " + String.valueOf(end) );   // Now - 1413551585985 END - 1413549900410
```

As you can see above, the `cal` instance is set to date as 17/10/2014 & time to 10:10. `cal.getTimeInMillis()` returns 1413555000396 that is saved in `endTime` variable. `endTime` is passed to `getPendingIntent()` and finally passed to intent using putExtra. When the intent receiver receives it, it shows value of `endTime` as 1413549900410 i.e. 8:45 time. Value of Now is correct i.e 09:13. My `endTime` was 10:10 which should not be greater than `now` value. I am comparing `now` with `endTime` value. But due to this incorrect value, it always shows now greater than endTime.

Any idea why does the value of `endTime` variable get changed in receiver ? I believe as I am using `Calendar.getInstance()` everywhere and `now` is also showing proper result, so it should not be a time zone issue.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: // END Time - 1413555000396 Apt Time - 10:10
// END Time - 1413555000905  i.e 10:10 CORRECT
// Now - 1413551585985 END - 1413549900410 , three different end times?

Comment: Oh ya. I am checking on http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm site & it shows me  17/10/14 10:10  value for 1413555000396 & 1413555000905. But it is wrong, you are right. But Strange, it differs between two methods also & I am not changing it anywhere. Why so ??

Comment: I replaced String.valueOf(endTime); with a DateFormat.format and I get proper endTime value in all places. Hmm.. does this mean that String.valueOf() changes the value of endTime someway & due to some reason. So usage of String.valueOf() is not advisable to use for date & times conversion !!!

Comment: what about if you use Float.toString? It should be the same but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `String.valueOf(endTime);` with a `DateFormat.format` and I get proper `endTime` value in all places.

Hmm.. does this mean that `String.valueOf()` changes the value of `endTime` someway & due to some reason. So I learned usage of `String.valueOf()` is not advisable to use for date & times conversion !!!